# opentelemetry collector azuremonitor exporter no metric or logs in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I have the following Opentelemetry collector configuration file

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

exporters:
  azuremonitor:
    instrumentation_key: {{ instrumentation_key }}
    spaneventsenabled: true
processors:
  batch:

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [azuremonitor]
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [azuremonitor]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [azuremonitor]
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: debug
```

I have a "working" demo that uses 2 vagrant VM and two basic springboot applications available at as well as some terraform that creates a application insights application available at

https://github.com/alikor/uptrace-demo

One manuel step i run the following on each VM

```
sudo docker run -d -v /etc/otel_config.yaml:/etc/otel/config.yaml -e OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=0.0.0.0:4317 -p 4317:4317 otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib --config /etc/otel/config.yaml
```

now from my observation of the docker logs of the opentelemetry collector the collector is receiving both

```
debug   azuremonitorexporter@v0.77.0/metric_to_envelopes.go:77  Metric is packed        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "azuremonitor", "name": "otlp.exporter.seen", "value": 16020}
debug   azuremonitorexporter@v0.77.0/factory.go:128     --------- Transmitting 59 items ---------       {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "azuremonitor"}
```

But this data is not being forwareded to the app insights agent trace information being successfully pushed but thats about it